# Inheritance variables not accessible

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to access the variables from inherited classes. However, the compiler gives the error:furniture.cpp:55:9: error: 'int stool::n_StoolLegs' is private within this context one.n_StoolLegs -1;.

This is a homework assignment however, the assignment says that I need to use 4 variables of type stool. So I inherited the class. Is there maybe another option to modify to modify the inherited variables?

furniture .hpp

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef FURNIURE_HPP
#define FURNITURE_HPP

class stool{
private:
    int n_StoolLegs;
    int n_seats;

public:
    void setStoolLegs(int);
    int getStoolLegs();
    void setSeats(int);
    int getSeats();    
};

class table {};//not relevant

class furniture: public stool, public table
{
private:
    stool one;
    stool two;
    stool three;
    stool four;

    table first;

public:
    furniture(){
    one.setStoolLegs(4);
    one.setSeats(1);

    void makeMoreHipster();

};


#endif
```

furniture.ccp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "furniture.hpp"

//begin stool
void stool::setStoolLegs (int nLegs){
    n_StoolLegs = nLegs;
};

int stool::getStoolLegs(){
    return n_StoolLegs;
};


void stool::setSeats (int nSeats){
    n_seats = nSeats;
};

int stool::getSeats(){
    return n_seats;
};
//end stool//


// begin table

//not relevant

// end table

//start furniture

void furniture::makeMoreHipster(){
    one.n_StoolLegs -1;


};

// end furniture//
```

Comment: `class furniture: public stool, public table` I don't think you want this design. You are saying a piece of furniture is both a stool and a table. Also it contains 4 stools and a table.

Comment: This is not a proper use of inheritance. Your design claims that any given `furniture` is a `stool` and also a `table`. In other words, there is no such thing as furniture that isn't a "stooltable". If inheritance is applicable at all here, `stool` and `table` are the ones that should inherit from `furniture` instead. This would express that a `stool` is `furniture` and a `table` is also `furniture`. But it looks like `furniture` is just meant to represent a collection of furniture-like objects, so inheritance shouldn't be used at all here.

Comment: The fact that members such as `n_StoolLegs` are `private` means that they must not be accessed from outside the class. This is not something inheritance will let you work around.

Comment: Instead of `one.n_StoolLegs -1;` maybe you wanted `one.setStoolLegs(one.getStoolLegs() -1);` or `one.setStoolLegs(3);`

Comment: Yeah, the design is backwards. The base class should be `Furniture`. `Table` and `Stool` should derive from `Furniture`, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

With inheritance, `private` variables are not accessible.
Use `protected`.

Comment: Technically, even this wouldn't help him, since he is not trying to reference (assign) inherited fields (`one.n_StoolLegs -1;`).